# What is the right usage of SIOCGIWSCAN to scan WIFI AP?

Tags: linux, wifi, socket, ioctl

I am working on an embedded Linux system (kernel 5.10.24), there is a WLAN interface in the system.

Now I want to scan the nearby AP, I *think* I can use socket and SIOCGIWSCAN command to get the AP list, but I cannot find detailed document on the usage of structure of `struct iwreq` in this scanning.

So is there any MAN page or example code on the `struct iwreq` and `SIOCGIWSCAN` for my reference?

Comment: Maybe because many network-related ioctl() methods are deprecated in favor of using the netlink(7) API? Searching "netlink wifi scan" on a search engine easily gives results. eg: https://github.com/bmegli/wifi-scan/blob/master/wifi_scan.c or https://alamot.github.io/nl80211/ (nothing about scanning there, but things about using netlink) , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18062268/using-nl80211-h-to-scan-access-points

Comment: Thanks for comment. Currently your comment is what I want to do. So you can post your comment as answer, and I would vote for it.